# How to print power of 2 in triangle form?

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to print the following:
[image: Power of 2 triangle]

but am not getting the result.
I tried the folowing:

```
for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ ))
do
    for (( j=1; j<=i;  j++ ))
    do
     echo -n "$((j**2))"
    done
    echo ""
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

- you print a square of j, not j power of 2;
- there is no power of two
  that is equal to zero;
- you need to print a space to separate figures;
- the initial value in loops should be not 1, but 0 to print 2**0 for
  completeness

Thus

```
for (( i=0; i<=5; i++ ))
do
    for (( j=0; j<=i;  j++ ))
    do
     echo -n "$((2 ** j)) "
    done
    echo ""
done
```

produces

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 4 
1 2 4 8 
1 2 4 8 16 
1 2 4 8 16 32
```